# twisted log in factory

Tags: logging, twisted

All good day.

Plz tell me what could be the problem. Do not print a log message from the factory

```
#!/usr/bin/env twistd --pidfile=storage_monitor.pid  --logfile=./logs/storage_twistd.log  -ny
from twisted.python import log
....    
class RedisMonitorProtocol(redis.SubscriberProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "p", datetime.datetime.now()
        log.msg("waiting for messages...")

....
class RedisMonitorFactory(redis.SubscriberFactory):
    maxDelay = 120
    protocol = RedisMonitorProtocol

    def __init__(self, conf):
        print "f",datetime.datetime.now()
        log.msg("+++++++++++++++++++++++++test1...")
        print "f",datetime.datetime.now()
```

Out in stdout

```
f 2015-07-09 14:03:37.039811
f 2015-07-09 14:03:37.039876
```

I see in log file "waiting for messages..." and "p 2015-07-09 14:03:37.130076"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Factory` is constructed (its `__init__` is called) before logging is initialized; logging starts once all the server components are built and passed to the application service, so that you can print messages to the administrator interactively before the log file consumes stdio.  That means that the `log.msg` calls don't go anywhere.  If you log in other methods of `Factory` such as `buildProtocol` you will see the log messages in your log file as you expect. In other words this has everything to do with *when* the code is run (before or after the log file is opened) rather than *where* the code is declared (what class it's on).

Comment: thank you!

please tell me how usually do logging in the project(may be some beg project on twisted)?
Why use ILogObserver?

Comment: You're doing it correctly, it's just that this early in start-up you are not going to be able to log messages.  You don't appear to be using `ILogObserver` directly here so I don't understand your follow-up question.